# Importing a file in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I tried to import the file only using `import` I searched the problem and found out it happened because the file isn't in the same working directory as my current file, didn't quite understand that(I am a beginner). So I tried using this: But still I get this error `No module named printer1`.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '\\' +  'C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\hello\\printer1.py'))
from printer1 import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\hello\\')
from printer1 import *
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It doesn't show that error anymore but I get in the code analysis a note that  `from printer1 import *` used; unable to detect undefined names

Comment: Ok. In the printer1 file do you have some functions defined right? with * you import all of them. Check that the name of the file is printer1 and then let me know :)